# SQLAlchemy using Execute

Tags: mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am having a hard time using group by, having, and sum all together in a manual query. Below is my query, can someone help me identify why it returns so many rows (as if it isn't applying the group by or having).

```
q = meta.Session.execute('SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(viewCount)= 0')
results = q.fetchall()
len(results)
```

Output from the above is **371**

If I run the query

```
SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(viewCount)=0;
```

Output from regular SQL is **17 rows found**

I tried utilizing the group_by that SQLAlchemy offers but I couldn't get it to work right with the having and the sum. I saw that I may need to include the func sum. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, when using raw sql you can't use the group_by or func.sum functions provided by SQLAlchemy. Also you should get rid of the aggregate function SUM at the end of your sql and just set viewCount=0